# Vuejs axios error when making post request

Tags: http, vue.js, axios

I'm new to vuejs and i'm following this tutorial 
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wy9q22isx3U&t=3492s).
When i tried to make a post request i got this error (has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.)
I could console.log(res.data) but i couldn't put it inside todos[] array.

```
addtodo(newTodo){
      const {title,completed} = newTodo;
      axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',{
        title,
        completed
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.todos = this.todos.push[res.data];
        //console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `.push()` wrong, it is parenthesis not bracket.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      todos:[{
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "delectus aut autem",
      "completed": false
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
      "completed": false
    }]
  },
  methods: {
   addtodo(newTodo){
      const {title,completed} = newTodo;
      axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',{
        title,
        completed
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.todos.push(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));  
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button @click="addtodo({title:'New todo',completed:true})">
  click to add todo
</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">{{todo.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried `this.todos = this.todos.push(res.data)` but it didn't work, can pls explain why

Comment: Ive edited my answer just use `this.todos.push(res.data)`. you don't have to assign it to a new variable. it will modify the original one and will return it's length.

Comment: `this.todos = this.todos.push(res.data)` if you do it like this it will return the new length of the `this.todos`. you will get a number. instead of the array

Answer (score 1):

no need to this.todos = this.todos.push() just use

```
this.todos.push(res.data)
```